# Apache Kafka Connector: Where to put global resources

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

Suppose I have something like a PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager or ActiveMQConnectionFactory that I need to use with my connector. I do not want to create one of these per task. Where do I place these objects in the connect framework?